# GWT - Implement programmatic tab selection of a TabLayoutPanel and then scroll to a particular element contained in the tab?

Tags: gwt, deferred-execution, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I have a TabLayout panel with 2 tabs. I would like to programmatically select the 2nd tab and then scroll to a particular element within the tab. This is how my code looks like:

```
public void scrollToTextArea(final String textArea)
{
    TabPanel.selectTab(1); //tab selection
    textArea.getElement().scrollIntoView(); //scroll to text area field
}
```

I tried using a deferred command to run the scroll portion, but was still unable to get the right display.

Is there a specific way to implement this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked:

```
public void scrollToTextArea(final String textArea)
{
    TabPanel.selectTab(1); //tab selection
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand()
        {
            public void execute()
            {
                textArea.getElement().scrollIntoView();
            }
        });
}
```